# Bubbling a CSS animation event

Tags: events, css

So according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Event/AnimationEvent) (it makes sense) the `AnimationEvent` has the `bubble` argument but how can one set it to true? Considering the event is fired from a CSS animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it turns out that CSS does bubble events, for example:

HTML:

```
<ul id="ul">
    <li>
        <a id="a">Some text!</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
a
{
    color: red;
}
a:hover
{
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;  
    -webkit-animation-name: change-color;
} 

@-webkit-keyframes change-color {  
    from 
    {  
        color: red;
    }  

    to 
    {  
        color: blue;
    }  
}
```

JS:

```
var a   = document.getElementById( 'a' );
var ul  = document.getElementById( 'ul' );

a.addEventListener( 'webkitAnimationEnd', handleEnd );
ul.addEventListener( 'webkitAnimationEnd', handleEnd );

function handleEnd(e)
{
    console.log(e);
}
```

You'll see two events fired. The problem I had was that I was using jQuery's `bind()` and this binds to a specific selector rather than listening to bubbled events (I think).